# How to create a tkinter background image?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I need to draw a ball moving on a canvas with a background (floor map) image. 
I succeded to load the image, and to draw the ball moving, but the canvas ball is not placed on top of the background.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
path = 'C:\xx\Pictures\xxx.jpg'
img = Image.open(path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 1, 1)
        self.canvas.after(50, self.draw)


canvas = tk.Canvas(root,  bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
background_label = tk.Label(root, image = photo)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0, anchor="center")
background_label.pack( )

ball = Ball(canvas, "red")
ball.draw()  #Changed per Bryan Oakley's comment.
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load the image in a label that's placed *below* the canvas you draw the ball in. You have to load the image in *the same* canvas.

Replace this

```
background_label = tk.Label(root, image = photo)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0, anchor="center")
background_label.pack( )
```

with this:

```
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)
```

Make sure to create the image before you create the ball to get the z-ordering right.